# xcode ignores table view cell height selection and uses table view row height selection

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, custom-cell

I'm creating a UItableView with two different dynamic custom cells and want both cells to have different default height. I can't seem to do this since the cells always take the height specified in the table view row height option instead of the table view cell height option.

Comment: Could you share the relevant code?

Comment: @Gordonium I'm not sure what code I'm supposed to post. Every thing works fine, the height of both cells change with the amount of contained text- the problem is that, I want the height of cell 1 to initially be 90 while the height of cell 2 to initially be 44 but when I run the program the heights of both cells are overwritten by the table view row height.